# MATLAB Force constructor method to be called when assigning default array elements

Tags: matlab

I have a class that assigns an immutable UUID to the object in its constructor. The following is a simplified illustration:

```
classdef mytest    
    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = immutable)        
        uuid        
    end    
    properties
        val
    end
    methods        
        function obj = mytest(valIn)
            obj.uuid = char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString);
            if nargin < 1
                valIn = 0;
            end
            obj.val = valIn;
        end
    end
end
```

This is working great in general, but I just discovered an issue with MATLAB's behaviour when assigning default elements to an array. I had assumed that if I typed

```
>> a(5) = mytest(2);
```

the constructor would be called 5 times - 4 times with no input arguments, to fill the default elements 1 to 4 of the array, and once with input argument `2` to assign the final element.

However, that's not what MATLAB does - instead it calls the constructor only once with no inputs, then copies the result four times to fill elements 1 to 4 (and then as expected for the final element). That means that the UUIDs ef elements 1 to 4 end up the same:

```
>> {a.uuid}'
ans = 
    '4424b91b-0977-4b4c-b18b-c4564875b952'
    '4424b91b-0977-4b4c-b18b-c4564875b952'
    '4424b91b-0977-4b4c-b18b-c4564875b952'
    '4424b91b-0977-4b4c-b18b-c4564875b952'
    'dbb8d862-8a1c-4bf9-876f-ef786e11a896'
```

It turns out this is documented behaviour that I just didn't expect, and I kind of understand why MathWorks have chosen to do that (you might not want the overhead of calling a no-input constructor many times separately).

But it's not the behaviour I want for this class - does anyone know of a way to force the constructor to be called for each element? Or perhaps you can suggest a different class design that would have the desired behaviour?

PS I did investigate whether MATLAB might be copying these default elements using a `copy` method - in which case inheriting my class from `matlab.mixin.Copyable`, and overriding the behaviour of `copyElement` might help - but it looks like that's not how it does the copying :(.

Comment: Isn't the problem that calling `a(5)` on a previously undefined variable tries to fill only the fifth element with what you're calling, and the rest should be 0 -- but in your case, the emptiest possible instance of your class? Have you tried `a(1:5) = mytest(2);` (probably won't work due to scalar expansion) or the same in a loop, setting the first 4 values to something?

Comment: @AndrasDeak No, that's not the issue. All of the first four values of `a` have the `val` property as `0` - that's expected and what I want, as the constructor is called with no input arguments. The issue is that the first four values of `a` all have the same UUID, as the constructor was not called separately for each of them.

Comment: That I understood. But does it make a difference if you call `a(1:4)=mytest();` first, or `for k=1:4, a(k)=mytest();`? I expect the first to not help, the second to help, but I can see why you wouldn't want to do the second one. There's [an example with random initialization in the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html#buod76n-1) that loops through the array...

Comment: Update: [another one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html) says "MATLAB calls the SimpleValue constructor once and copies the returned object to each element of the array". Suspicious.

Comment: Of course - `for k=1:4, a(k)=mytest(); end` assigns them all separately, and `a(1:4)=mytest();` doesn't, in the way described in the question. I'm not asking about the first situation though, I'm asking about how to control the behaviour of my class in the second situation.It's not about "why I would want to", I'll be sharing the class with others, and need to control its behaviour correctly whatever they choose to type.

Comment: If you add a `disp( ['in constructor: nargin=' num2str(nargin)] );` in the constructor you can see that the class is called twice.  Once to fill 5 and then once to backfill items 1:4).  (as you experience).  Could you live with updating the `obj.uuid` when items 1 to 4 are used later?

Comment: @matlabgui So for my personal use yes, that would be fine. But I'll be sharing the class and can't control how users will call it, so I'm trying to ensure that the class behaves sensibly even if they _don't_ do that.

Comment: Though it might not help in your case, the most robust general solution is to create your own container class and force your users to use that instead of a Matlab array. That way you can control exactly how the array is initialised. The problem really boils down to the way that Matlab arrays work, rather than how the objects in the array are constructed. If you modify the class itself you might be able to fix this specific problem, but you might end up introducing side effects/behaviour that your users are not expecting. But that might be acceptable depending on your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with MATLAB classes.

Looking at [the relevant docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html) it seems that you're doing everything right, and so is MATLAB:

> `a(1,7) = SimpleValue(7)`
>
> The object assigned to array element `a(1,7)` uses the input argument passed to the constructor as the value assigned to the property:
>
> ...
>
> MATLAB created the objects contained in elements `a(1,1:6)` with no input argument. The default value for properties empty `[]`.
>
> ...
>
> MATLAB calls the `SimpleValue` constructor once and copies the returned object to each element of the array.

This suggests that what you're experiencing is documented behaviour: automatic allocation of previously unassigned array elements is done with a *single* call to the constructor with zero input arguments.

This is also in agreement with [another example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html#buod76n-1) using a random initializer: the example code uses

```
for k = 1:5
   a(k) = ObjProp;
end
```

to set the 5 elements of the array such that they contain different random data. At least from the documentation, this seems to be the work-around for your problem: initializing each empty element by hand (which is probably not what you want to do).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but this doesn't answer the question - I realize that there's no issue if I initialize the elements by hand individually. But I'll be sharing the class, and am not able to ensure that users will do that. I'm looking for a way to control the behaviour of the class, so that it does the right thing when they _don't_ do that.

Comment: @SamRoberts thanks, and I read your comment above as well. I mean it as an answer: at least from the documentation it seems that "you can't do that" is the answer. I'll keep this here, and hope that someone more MATLAB-OOP-savvy will come and prove me wrong:) But it seems ingrained in MATLAB to call the constructor only once for automatic initialization.

Comment: No problem - do keep your answer here, as it's looking like "you can't do that" may well be the answer :(. My only thought currently is that I might be able to overload `subsasgn` in a complicated way, so that it detects if it's being asked to assign to an element that doesn't yet exist, calls the constructor separately for each new element, then does the actual assignment. But that seems like it might be very hard, and error-prone.

Comment: @SamRoberts so just to be clear: have you actually tried deriving from `matlab.mixin.Copyable` (as you hinted in the question) and making it such that copying generates a new `uuid`, perhaps by setting it [`NonCopyable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/custom-copy-behavior.html#but7_ra)? (I don't know if using a handle class is compatible with your application.)

Comment: I've tried deriving from `matlab.mixin.Copyable` and making `copyElement` generate a new uuid - but the copying process for creating default elements doesn't seem to call `copy`. I haven't tried `NonCopyable` - I need to support R2014a, and `NonCopyable` is more recent than that. I do have access to R2015b though, so out of interest I will try to look into whether that would work. I suspect it will not make any difference, as the process doesn't call `copy` anyway.

Comment: Though if you're concerned about other users, be aware that changing `copy` methods might introduce side effects or behaviour they don't expect. What if a user wants to store the same object twice in the same array for whatever reason? They might not expect the uuid to change in one of the objects.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it seems to be the case that you basically can't do what I was hoping.

Comment: @SamRoberts thank you, and I'm sorry that what you want didn't work out.